# Google Play Game Services App-Login Stuck On White Screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-authentication, google-play-games

When I attempt to sign in to game services in my mobile game I get a white modal box with a refresh symbol on it and nothing else happens (Gets stuck there). If I press outside that modal it prompts me to select which account to login to, after-which it shows the same white box.

I recently activated google game services for my mobile app (in beta testing) to setup cloud saves and leaderboards. I setup my OAuth2 correctly using the SHA-1 certificate, and added my self as a tester for the game services. Also double checked to make sure that my app has the correct application-id that is found in the google-play-console.

The game-services them selves are still in draft mode which I believe is fine as long as I have internal testers.

Any help is appreciated as I been stuck on this for 2 weekends now.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue seems to be the consent screen, I had to publish my consent screen to get this to work. Once I published the consent screen I was finally able to see the permissions UI, after which I was successfully signed in.

More info:

[Google Play Games Services Signin Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114137/google-play-games-services-signin-problems)

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2999

Hope this helps someone save a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

As it said at *OAuth consent screen* page in *Google Cloud Platform*:

> While publishing status is set to "Testing", only test users are able
> to access the app.

You have to go to that page and add tester emails or publish consent screen to production state.